# Discrepancies with checking ports from docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, nmap

I've used to check the port statuses with the `netstat` and `nmap` utils.

I ran an application with an incorrect port mapping (`bitnami/redis` in this example):

```
# docker-compose.yml part (4444 as a random nonexistent port)
ports:
  - '7000:4444'

# Nestat shows that it's alive
netstat -naptu | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7000            0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      22893/docker-proxy 

nmap -p 7000 0.0.0.0 -->  7000/tcp open
nmap -p 7000 127.0.0.1 -->  7000/tcp open
nmap -p 7000 192.168.0.1 -->  7000/tcp closed
```

As you can see it's open for the `localhost` and is closed for some reason for the external interface.

Now the same with the correct setup:

```
# docker-compose.yml part
ports:
  - '7000:6379'

netstat -naptu | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7000            0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      22893/docker-proxy

nmap -p 7000 0.0.0.0 -->  7000/tcp open
nmap -p 7000 127.0.0.1 -->  7000/tcp open
nmap -p 7000 192.168.0.1 -->  7000/tcp open
```

I may guess that a docker sets up some kind of the proxy that makes netstat show that the port is `LISTEN` for any kind of the mapping. But I can't get why did it show that the port was open for the `localhost` in case when the mapping was incorrect. And why it was not open to the `external` interface as well then.